# Использование функций класса для всех объектов этого класса

Tags: python

Можно ли каким-то образом сделать так, что бы все объекты определенного класса выполнили нужную функцию этого класса? Например, мы создали очень много объектов и переписывать строку вызова функции для всех было бы весьма долго.

```
class Myclass
    def Function():
    print ("просто функция")

object1 = Myclass()
object2 = Myclass()
object3 = Myclass()
...
```

Далее идет обильное кол-во подобных объектов, для каждого из которых надо будет 
применить функцию Function.
Как можно заменить такое большое количество строк:

```
object1.Function()
object2.Function()
object3.Function()
и т.д.
```

Comment: Почему бы не хранить объекты в списке?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста ваш пример и объясните лучше какой метод вы хотите выполнить для всех объектов класса.

Comment: object1,2,3 отлично кладутся в один список, по которому потом можно пройтись циклом в две строчки

Comment: А если необходимо создавать объекты много раз из одного места кода командой Myclass(), например, в функции размножения в простенькой симуляции жизни?

Comment: Нужное количество раз добавлять в список, очевидно

Comment: А можете пожалуйста подсказать, каким образом можно будет вызвать функцию для объектов, хранящихся в списке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы рассмотрел такое решение

```
class Myclass

    def Function():
       print ("просто функция")    
objects = []

o1 = Myclass()
objects.append(o1)
o2 = Myclass()
objects.append(o2)
o3 = Myclass()
objects.append(o3)

def do_function(objects):
   for object in objects:
      object.Function()
```

Так же можно сделать процедуру создания объекта, которая будет создавать объект и заносить его в массив объектов.

Comment: Обратите внимание. Если вы просто скопировали код, то там была допущена ошибка. В процедуре do_function() в самой посленей скобке нужны скобки()